# What or who am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

This is my first post (**not** a clue).

> Most people hate me.
>
> I rarely get my chance to shine.
>
> You likely won't see me, but when you do it won't be for long.
>
> I love to play. Meow.
>
> I have 4 forms, but only my dedicated followers see 3 of them.
>
> I hate meeting my friends.
>
> What or who am I?

Hint 1

> Very specific knowledge is required for this one.

Hint 2

> I need a computer to live.

Hint 3

> This is a video game character from a very popular online game.

Comment: sounds like some pokemon to me.  Meow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ...

> Rengar, from League of Legends

Most people hate me.

> not a popular choice, and (empowered) battle roar is a royal pain to the enemy

I rarely get my chance to shine.

> not played all that well all that often?

You likely won't see me, but when you do it won't be for long.

> Thrill of the Hunt keeps you stealthed when not taking damage

I love to play. Meow.

> You is feral kitty.

I have 4 forms, but only my dedicated followers see 3 of them.

> Rengar, Headhunter Rengar, Night Hunter Rengar, SSW Rengar.
>  these are rather costly to buy (and the last one is no longer avail)

I hate meeting my friends.

> Not sure about this one.

Comment: Nice job on solving it, Rubio! My apologies for the rather vague hints, this was my first puzzle. The last hint was meant to represent how assassin champions don't like teamfights and would rather be by themselves picking people off. Nice job!

Answer (score 2):

I think

> The Moon

Most people hate me.

> Moon symbolises old age and illness

I rarely get my chance to shine.

> The moon shines on the light of the sun, it does not glow on its own.

You likely won't see me, but when you do it won't be for long.

> Only at night, and most people tend to watch the stars rather than moon

I love to play. Meow.

I have 4 forms, but only my dedicated followers see 3 of them.

> 4 forms of the moon- Full moon, crescent and half moon, the other being the new moon. Play might refer to some mythological significance of which I am not aware of.

I hate meeting my friends.

> It hasn't got any. Those of the other "parents" are too far away.

2nd attempt

> Mouse

Most people hate me.

> Of course, they do.

I rarely get my chance to shine.

> You scare off a mouse.. never let them cut things at peace

You likely won't see me, but when you do it won't be for long.

> Only for a split second. By the time, you get terrified, they disappear

I love to play. Meow.

> Tom and Jerry!! Plays with a cat.

I have 4 forms, but only my dedicated followers see 3 of them

> No idea-might have got to do something with the life cycle of a mouse

I hate meeting my friends.

> Yeah, it would have to share the cheese!

Hint2

> Mouse on a computer

Comment: Very interesting answer - I hadn't thought of this! Sadly it's not the answer I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is

> Death

Most people hate me.

> Don't you?

I rarely get my chance to shine.

> It does in gladiator matches, but not much lately

You likely won't see me, but when you do it won't be for long.

> You see the end in the light of the tunnel, but probably only for a brief second.

I love to play. Meow.

> You play with death... Why death says Meow? I don't know!

I have 4 forms, but only my dedicated followers see 3 of them.

> 1. Come to heaven. 2. Re-incarnation. 3. Come to hell. 4. Just rot in the ground, nothing more. I don't know why only the dedicated followers get to see 3.

I hate meeting my friends.

> Well, once death meets his friends, his friends will die. It's better not to meet them!

**Note: I haven't read the hints.**

Comment: I suppose it makes sense, but it's not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Though I think the riddle would be easier being solved by certain gamers, still I am here, giving a try.

I guess you are

> [Teemo](http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/teemo/) from *League of Legends*

*Most people hate me.*

> According to [a game forum discussion](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3632303&page=1), it seemed that most players hate Teemo, some even *without specific reason*.

*I rarely get my chance to shine.*

> I guess because of the fact that Teemo's abilities made it hard for players to make high damage to others.

*You likely won't see me, but when you do it won't be for long.*

> It's because of Teemo's *Camouflage* ability that made him able to become stealthed easily. That's **the key line** for me to came up with such a champion.

*I love to play. Meow.*

> I'm not sure about this line. Teemo looks like a cat, indeed. Maybe it is about Teemo's Yordle origin?

*I have 4 forms, but only my dedicated followers see 3 of them.*

> I have *completely no idea* about this line.

*I hate meeting my friends.*

> I got no clue from this line, either.

Alright, here's my second guess:

You are

> [Rengar](http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/rengar/) from *League of Legends*

*Most people hate me.*

> According to a [discussion](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/gameplay-balance/0hR6KE4d-why-do-people-say-rengar-takes-no-skill-and-hate-on-rengar-mains), Rengar is an *assassin*. In a PvE game such as LoL, an assassin could be a terrible teammate.

*I rarely get my chance to shine.*

> Born as a hunter, Rengar's roll have made him suitable to ambush in the jungle, rather than fighting in the frontline.

*You likely won't see me, but when you do it won't be for long.*

> This refers to Rengar's stealth ability, and able to kill a rival in a short period of time - especially in the late phase of game.

*I love to play. Meow.*

> Rengar is actually a lion, in other words, a *big cat*. He loves challenge, a quote in the official introduction could describe:
>  
>  *"He feared that no worthwhile game remained, that he would never again feel the thrill of the hunt."*

*I have 4 forms, but only my dedicated followers see 3 of them.*

> It refers to Rengar's different *skin*. Playing Rengar require some patient, skill of moving, and the awareness of the map, so I think there was fewer player - those *dedicated followers* - can see his form other than the first one received. However, the *fourth form* is no longer available, because it came from a special event. (reference [here](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/skins?sort_type=&sort_order=&champion_id=103&skinType=&is_available=))

*I hate meeting my friends.*

> This may refers to the change in set-up relationship between Rengar and another champion Nidalee - once friends, yet rivals now.

Comment: You're definitely the closest one! Keep in mind that League of Legends has several stealth champions, as well as several feline champions.

Comment: @Danilo A second guess has edited, with complete explanation. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its

> Deoxys from Pokemon.

*Most people hate me.*

> In the film, its an aggressive Pokemon who destroys the city

*I rarely get my chance to shine.*

> I have no idea..

*You likely won't see me, but when you do it won't be for long.*

> Because it can fled.

*I love to play. Meow.*

> Maybe because its a bored legendary Pokemon?

*I have 4 forms, but only my dedicated followers see 3 of them.*

> Deoxys has 4 forms, Defense, Normal, Attack and Speed. You cant find the speed one, because of his high speed.

*I hate meeting my friends.*

> He dont have any.

Despite the great match with the fifth line, this probably won't be the answer (the game isnt known of the online game capabilities), but I thought I share it.